# Prove maximum of function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

I have a function

$$f(x,k) = \frac{x^{p-k} \prod_{j=0}^k K_j}{\sum_{i=0}^p (x^{p-i} \prod_{j=0}^i K_j)}$$

for $k=0,...,p$, where $K_0:=1$ and $x$ is real positive. How can one prove that the value of $x$ which maximises $f(x,k)$ for a given $k$ is the root of

$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^p ((p-i)x^{p-i} \prod_{j=0}^i K_j)}{\sum_{i=0}^p (x^{p-i} \prod_{j=0}^i K_j)} = p-k$$

for $k=1,...,p-1$, which numerically seems to work as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Pi_{j=0}^i K_j=a_i$ for $i=1\dots p$, then

$$f'(x,k)=x^{p-k-1}a_k\frac{(p-k)\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i-x\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i-1}a_i}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i\right)^2}
$$

Now, $$f'(x,k)=0\implies(p-k)\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i-x\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i-1}a_i=0,$$

and, therefore

$$
\begin{aligned}(p-k)\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i&=x\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i-1}a_i,\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i}a_i.
\end{aligned}$$

This results in
$$
\begin{aligned}(p-k)&=
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i}a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^p (p-i)x^{p-i}\Pi_{j=0}^i K_j}{\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}\Pi_{j=0}^i K_j}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to prove that its a maximum (the second derivative is <0)? We know always that $x>0$, p,k some positive natural integers ($k \leq p$), $K_j>0$ for all j

Comment: Also, what about the possibility that the derivative denominator $\sum_{i=1}^p x^{p-i}a_i - x = 0$?

Comment: I actually don't find any $-x$ term in the denominator. You may want to check where that came from

Comment: @MobeusZoom Yes, it was a typo